Why is a Before Update Trigger firing whenever I open a Record?
I have this problem that whenever I open a Case record the Last Modified Date gets changed to the current date/time. Debugging I've found that the Before Update Trigger is firing when I open the record and running a method.
The method is this here if it helps:
    public override void beforeUpdate(){
        otherMethod1();
        setBusinessHours((List<Case>)Trigger.new);
        otherMethod2();
    }

    private static void setBusinessHours(List<Case> newCases) {
    Map<String, String> businessHoursLabelToCountryMap = new Map<String, String>{
        '4'  => 'UK', // EU_English
        '12' => 'UK', // US_English
        '9'  => 'IT FR DE', // FR_French
        '15' => 'UK', // EX_English
        '21' => 'IT FR DE', // CH_Deutsche  
        '22' => 'IT FR DE', // CH_French
        '20' => 'IT FR DE', // CH_Italian
        '1'  => 'IT FR DE', // IT_Italian
        '5'  => 'ES', // EU Spanish  
        '6'  => 'IT FR DE', // EU German
        '8'  => 'IT FR DE', // EU French
        '11' => 'UK', // UK English
        '14' => 'ES', // US Spanish,
        '41' => 'UK', //CA_English
        '44' => 'IT FR DE', //CA_French
        '0'  => 'IT FR DE' // Unknown
    };
    List<BusinessHours> businessHoursList = [Select Id, Name From BusinessHours];
    Map<String, BusinessHours> businessHoursMap = new Map<String, BusinessHours>();
    for(BusinessHours businessHoursRecord : businessHoursList){
        businessHoursMap.put(businessHoursRecord.Name, businessHoursRecord);
    }
    for(Case caseRecord : newCases) {
        String storeView = caseRecord.StoreView__c;
        String businessHoursName = String.isNotBlank(storeView) && businessHoursLabelToCountryMap.containsKey(storeView) ? businessHoursLabelToCountryMap.get(storeView) : 'IT FR DE';
        caseRecord.BusinessHoursId = businessHoursMap.containsKey(businessHoursName) ?  businessHoursMap.get(businessHoursName).Id : null;
    }
}

Why is that happening?

Your issue is how the trigger is getting invoked at all - it should not be running when simply viewing a record. It's likely there might be a custom component in the page firing the update when it loads. I recommend you look into the flexipage for Cases, see if there are any components that might be causing this (some components might not have any content to display, so keep an eye out for those too).

@kkola I'm pretty sure this is the answer, I checked and there's a flow component running an update on the case to mark the emails as read. It's a screen flow, I'm guessing it runs automatically as soon as the page is open? I'm not really knowledgeable on flows

Yes -- the screen flow should be redesigned so that no DML occurs until the user clicks a button on the flow (e.g. NEXT). Otherwise every page refresh will do DML
